# Sprout Form submit: The CSRF token could not be verified!

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I have a form created by Sprout Forms, which results in an error when submitted:

The CSRF token could not be verified!

Here is the log:

```
2016/06/09 11:06:17 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.400] exception 'Craft\HttpException' with message 'The CSRF token could not be verified.' in /home/forge/www.fira.co.uk/craft/app/services/HttpRequestService.php:1314
Stack trace:
#0 /home/forge/www.fira.co.uk/craft/app/framework/base/CComponent.php(561): Craft\HttpRequestService->validateCsrfToken(Object(CEvent))
#1 /home/forge/www.fira.co.uk/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(212): CComponent->raiseEvent('onBeginRequest', Object(CEvent))
#2 /home/forge/www.fira.co.uk/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(183): CApplication->onBeginRequest(Object(CEvent))
#3 /home/forge/www.fira.co.uk/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#4 /home/forge/www.fira.co.uk/public/index.php(19): require_once('/home/forge/www...')
#5 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/publications/industry-statistics
HTTP_REFERER=http://www.fira.co.uk/publications/industry-statistics
```

Comment: Which version of Sprout Forms are you using?  Can you update your question to give an example of how are you outputting the form on your page (displayForm tag vs. custom, etc.)?  Also, is it possible you have a {% cache %} tag wrapped around your form?  A CSRF token needs to be unique for each submission.

Comment: Ben, you're a star, you made me realise that the form (which uses the basic function to output the form to a page) was indeed wrapped in a cache tag.

Answer (score 2):

The form code in the template was wrapped in a `{% cache %}` tag.